# Value is disappearing while typing into combo box

Tags: extjs

I have a combo box. When I try to search for a name, the value I am entering is disappearing automatically and the search isn't happening properly.
But If I am selecting from the drop-down list, then it is working properly.

**Problems:**

1. After putting something in combobox field, it is disappearing automatically.
2. The user isn't able to search for a name by inserting first few letters.
3. The Name isn't coming as per priority wise.

I have tried typeAhead, but it isn't working.

Code:

```
          xtype: 'combobox',
                    itemId: 'abc_VendorName',
                    inputId: 'abc_VendorName',
                    cls: 'FieldLabel',
                    margin: '0 0 3 0',
                    fieldLabel: 'Vendor Name:',
                    labelSeparator: '',                   
                    msgTarget: 'side',
                    displayField: 'namewithSLID',
                    valueField: 'code',
                    matchFieldWidth: false,
                    forceSelection: true,
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    minChars: 1,
                    pageSize: 25,
                    listeners: {
                        change: 'onVendorNameChange',
                        blur: 'onVendorNameBlur'
                    },
```

The two listeners-

```
onVendorNameChange: function (combo, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        var view = me.getView();
        var viewmodel = me.getViewModel();

        if (combo.getValue() > 0) {
            var selectedRecord = combo.selection;
            if (selectedRecord == null || selectedRecord === undefined) {
                return;
            }

            var alias = selectedRecord.get('abbreviation');
            var finslCode = selectedRecord.get('code');

            view.down("#dspl_VendorAlias").setValue(alias);

            viewmodel.get('theRecord').set('finslAbbreviation', selectedRecord.get('abbreviation'));
            viewmodel.get('theRecord').set('finslSLID', selectedRecord.get('slid'));

            me.implementVendorItemMarkup(finslCode);
        }
    },


onVendorNameBlur: function (combo, event, eOpts) {
        var me = this;
        var view = me.getView();
        var viewmodel = me.getViewModel();

        if (combo.getValue() == null) {
            view.down("#dspl_VendorAlias").setValue(null);
            viewmodel.get('theRecord').set('finslAbbreviation', null);
            viewmodel.get('theRecord').set('finslSLID', null);
        }
    },
```

Comment: try to alter the function onVendorNameChange to be called in the 'select' event instead of 'change' event

Comment: Not working....

Comment: Can you tell me why the values are disappearing while typing?

Comment: what this does? me.implementVendorItemMarkup(finslCode);

Comment: @FabioBarros it fetches the combobox data